# Edit Page option in chatter tab

Tags: chatter, tab, edit

I enabled chatter in my org. I want to add some custom components in the chatter page layout. So I tried to Navigate 'Setup--->Edit Page'. But I couldn't find Edit Page. Please provide a solution.

[image]